# ANCOVA assumption independence violated

Tags: anova, independence, assumptions, ancova

I need some additional advice on my study.

I plan to look at differences in constituents of several vegetable varieties. Now, this could be solved with a simple Anova, but my colleagues want to include the size of the single measured vegetables as the size may have an effect on the amount of the constituent. I dont have any data yet, but I wanted to look at the statistical procedure beforehand.

I have thought about including the size as a covariate and run an ANCOVA, however, the covariate is very likely not independent from the variety. My understanding would be that this violates a model assumption.
Now I read up on the problem and some say that it is the worst thing to ever happen, some say an ANCOVA can still be done, like here:

> If however, [...], the main categorical independent variable is observed and not manipulated, the independence assumption between the covariate and the independent variable is irrelevant."
> https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/assumptions-of-ancova/

I am also unsure of the importance of the covariate. Since size will very likely depend on variety anyway, I am not sure how much more the inclusion of this covariate will explain compared to just use variety alone.

Here is how the data structure looks like for understanding:

| Variety | diameter [cm] | Value [%] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4.3 |
| B | 1 | 5.1 |
| C | 2 | 2.5 |

Is there any way to include diameter in the study even if it (likely) depends on variety or is it better to leave it all together?

Thanks for any help, if the are understanding problems I will gladly add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are applying ANCOVA to a non-randomized treatment situation.  Treatment is orthogonal to the other factors when you randomize, otherwise usually not.  The answer to your question comes down to the question of interest.   In many situations the more interesting question is for example to what extent an amount varies over varieties after taking size into account.  If that is the question, then adjusting for the non-independent size factor is appropriate.   Note that in some setting it is sometimes better to size-normalize then analyze.

When randomization is not used it may be better to call this a multivariable linear model instead of ANCOVA.